# European Postal Shipping Costs

Tags: europe

I am looking for datasets or ideally public APIs which would provide an estimate for postal shipping costs between 2 countries in Europe.

For example, given object size/dimensions/weight --> return an estimate for the costs of shipping it, between any 2 countries (or just between country A and B - it would be a start for me).

Does anyone know of such a service or where could I look further? (searching brought me to several such resources but for US only - I am specifically interested for the EU).

Comment: Googling "shipping costs europe" (no quotes) returns several results, and it appears shipping with the EU has a "fixed" consistent cost. Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that each country has a "national" as well as several other postal services - and their costs vary depending on origin, destination, size, dimensions etc... I was hoping that someone maybe knows of an aggregated dataset / public API which collects such information pan-Europa. Googling brings back "only" a few of these service providers.